# Preserving the failure mode of a parser in Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

#### Problem statement

Suppose I have two parsers `p` and `q` and I concatenate them like this:

```
r = try p *> q
```

In Parsec, the behavior of this is:

- If `p` fails without consuming input, then `r` fails without consuming input.
- If `p` fails after consuming input, then `r` fails without consuming input.
- if `q` fails without consuming input, then `r` fails after consuming `p`.
- if `q` fails after consuming input, then `r` fails after consuming `p` and parts of `q`.

However, the behavior I'm looking for is a bit unusual:

- If `p` fails without consuming input, then `r` should fail without consuming input.
- If `p` fails after consuming input, then `r` should fail without consuming input.
- if `q` fails without consuming input, then `r` *should fail without consuming input.*
- if `q` fails after consuming input, then `r` should fail after consuming some input.

I can't seem to think of a clean way to do this.

#### Rationale

The reason is that I have a parser like this:

```
s = (:) <$> q <*> many r
```

The `q` parser, embedded inside the `r` parser, needs a way to signal either: invalid input (which occurs when `q` consumes input but fails), or end of the `many` loop (which occurs when `q` doesn't consume anything and fails).  If the input is invalid, it should just fail the parser entirely and report the problem to the user.  If there is no more input to consume, then it should end the `many` loop (without reporting a parser error to the user).  The trouble is that it's possible that the input ends with a `p` but without any more valid `q`'s to consume, in which case `q` will fail but without consuming any input.

So I was wondering if anyone have an elegant way to solve this problem?  Thanks.

#### Addendum: Example

```
p = string "P"
q = (++) <$> try (string "xy") <*> string "z"
```

Test input on (hypothetical) parser `s`, had it worked the way I wanted:

1. `xyz` (accept)
2. `xyzP` (accept; `P` remains unparsed)
3. `xyzPx` (accept; `Px` remains unparsed; `q` failed but did not consume any input)
4. `xyzPxy` (reject; parser `q` consumed `xy` but failed)
5. `xyzPxyz` (accept)

In the form `r = try p *> q`, `s` will actually reject both case #2 and case #3 above.  Of course, it's possible to achieve the above behavior by writing:

```
r = (++) <$> try (string "P" *> string "xy") <*> string "z"
```

but this isn't a general solution that works for any parsers `p` and `q`.  (Perhaps a general solution doesn't exist?)

Comment: Would `try (try p *> q)` not work?

Comment: `try` discards all information about the progress of the input (i.e. maps both kinds of failures to "failure without consuming input") so you can't emulate the behavior described with only `try`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found a solution. It's not especially nice, but seems to works. At least something to start with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Applicative hiding (many, (<|>))
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Text.Parsec hiding (optional)
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String

rcomb ::  (Stream s m t) => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m b -> ParsecT s u m b
rcomb p q = ((test $ opt p *> opt q) <|> pure (Just ()))
                >>= maybe empty (\_ -> p *> q)
  where
    -- | Converts failure to @MaybeT Nothing@:
    opt = MaybeT . optional -- optional from Control.Applicative!
    -- | Tests running a parser, returns Nothing if parsers failed consuming no
    -- input, Just () otherwise.
    test = lookAhead . try . runMaybeT . void
```

This is the `r` combinator you're asking for. The idea is that we first execute the parsers in a "test" run (using `lookAhead . try`) and if any of them fails without consuming input, we record it as `Nothing` inside `MaybeT`. This is accomplished by `opt`, it converts a failure to `Nothing` and wraps it into `MaybeT`. Thanks to `MaybeT`, if `opt p` returns `Nothing`, `opt q` is skipped.

If both `p` and `q` succeed, the `test ..` part returns `Just ()`. And if one of them consumes input, the whole `test ..` fails. This way, we distinguish the 3 possibilities:

1. Failure with some input consumed by `p` or `q`.
2. Failure such that the failing part doesn't consume input.
3. Success.

After `<|> pure (Just ())` both 1. and 3. result in `Just ()`, while 2. results in Nothing. Finally, the `maybe` part converts `Nothing` into a non-consuming failure, and `Just ()` into running the parsers again, now without any protection. This means that 1. fails again with consuming some input, and 3. succeeds.

Testing:

```
samples =
    [ "xyz" -- (accept)
    , "xyzP" -- (accept; P remains unparsed)
    , "xyzPz" -- (accept; Pz remains unparsed)
    , "xyzPx" -- (accept; Px remains unparsed; q failed but did not consume any input)
    , "xyzPxy" -- (reject; parser q consumed xy but failed)
    , "xyzPxyz" -- (accept)
    ]

main = do
    -- Runs a parser and then accept anything, which shows what's left in the
    -- input buffer:
    let run p x = runP ((,) <$> p <*> many anyChar) () x x

    let p, q :: Parser String
        p = string "P"
        q = (++) <$> try (string "xy") <*> string "z"

    let parser = show <$> ((:) <$> q <*> many (rcomb p q))
    mapM_ (print . run parser) samples
```

Comment: I've added an example to the post.  Your examples don't quite fit the criteria as failures within `q` that *do* consume input will get silently dropped.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  It works exactly as I wanted.  However, will the lookahead cause `p` and `q` to be run twice on any given input?

Comment: @fzlogic Unfortunately yes :(, I couldn't think of a way how to run it only once. The problem is that we use `Nothing` to signal that no input should be consumed. But then the only option is to look-ahead without consuming any input and run the parsers twice.

Comment: @fzlogic There is an elegant solution that doesn't involve double parsing, but requires a function that uses Parsec's internal. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haskell-cafe/5eCPIzZr5ZQ/nZG0b3yzZiAJ).

Comment: Ah I see, so I guess the main problem is the lack of a primitive that preserves the failure mode.